# Implement Apple Maps Map Location Information in iOS app

Tags: ios

When you open Apple Maps, and click on a point of interest, a small annotation window pops up. If you click on the detail disclosure on the right side of the window,  a new view controller opens up which has lots of information about the point of interest. (Phone number, website, address, hours, etc.)

In my app, I'm pulling a list of local restaurants with MKLocalSearch, which comes up with the list of local points of interest. Is there any way to get this view controller, with all of the associated information, into my iOS app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide this for you "for free". But nothing stops *you* from making a view controller which you populate with the "associated information" — if you have access to that information.

Comment: I figured as much. It would have been too easy otherwise! Thanks.